# Is there a way to get the DatabaseMetaData object from a Mybatis connection?

Tags: mybatis, spring-mybatis

In other words I want an equivalent of [this](http://kodejava.org/how-do-i-use-databasemetadata-to-get-table-column-names/) for Mybatis

```
DatabaseMetaData metadata = connection.getMetaData();
```

Comment: In the end, you can of course get a Connection from MyBatis. But the question is probably your use case... What objects do you have from which you want the metadata?

Comment: Well i need it for my schema (db) : tables, columns and keys